# Import text from specific CSV cells to be used as HTML code (JQuery? PHP?)

Tags: php, jquery, html, csv, import

Complete novice with a very simple text-based webpage. Not sure whether to use PHP, JQuery, Javascript, or what, but I just want to pull text from a specified range of cells of a CSV file (located on server) to be used as HTML code; for example, this is the content of cells N2-N3:

```
<p><sup>1</sup>&nbsp;In the beginning<span class="CNC"></span> <span class="I"></span> created the heavens and the earth.</p>
<p><sup>2</sup>&nbsp;And the earth was <i class="alt" data-text='["without form","formless"]'></i> and <i class="alt" data-text='["void","empty"]'></i>.</p>
```

CSV details: 34 columns. 31103 rows (first is field names). Separator is %.

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zZpJy/20/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would ACTUALLY drop the csv into a database - this is VERY easy as you have it in CSV format with column names in the first row (using PHP my admin - then import.)

Then you can just query the database.

Otherwise (lets say you want the data in row 30504 - you have to read the whole file to row 30504 to get the data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! You'll have to forgive me, but how do you do this? Also, do you know if what you're suggesting (PHP my admin) is the standard way of dealing with large amounts of data to be selectively displayed online? Is that how a typical online Bible would be housed? Are there are any alternative options worth mentioning, other than PHP my admin, I mean?

Comment: PHPmyAdmin is just a graphical way to view a database and make manually ammendments (plus run some queries) etc. What you ACTUALLY need is mySQL and PHP - however there are hundreds of languages and database types out there - I just suggest that is a good place to start. With regards to on-line Bibles I am not 100% what the standard way of doing that is but adding each page to a database would be a great place to start - worrying how to optimise it comes when your understanding grows.